# System.NotSupportedException: The data source does not support server-side data paging.?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle11g

This is my code:

```
query = "SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(date,'DD-Mon-YYYY')date, idNum, name FROM customer  ORDER BY date, idNum, name";
        dset = dbCon.ExecuteDataSet(query);
        grdSat.DataSource = query;
        grdSat.DataBind();
```

I got an error at here :

```
grdSat.DataBind();
```

and when I debug the coding, this is what I got :

**NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should assign the `dataset` to the grid. Like this:

```
grdSat.DataSource = dset;
grdSat.DataBind();
```